# "Kinesis data delivery streams" is the same with "Kinesis data stream"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Please explain what is **Kinesis data delivery stream** is. Is it the same with [Amazon Kinesis Data Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-streams/getting-started) or is this a technology specific to Firehose?

- [Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose features](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/features/)

  > **Kinesis data delivery stream** is the underlying entity of Kinesis Data Firehose. You use Kinesis Data Firehose by creating a Kinesis data delivery stream and then sending data to it.

Answer (score 1):

To use Firehose, you create `Kinesis Data Firehose delivery stream`. This is an entity which processes data and delivers it outcome to your destination, e.g. S3 or Redshift.

However, you have to ingest some data to the `Kinesis Data Firehose delivery stream` to start with. The data can by ingested directly, by using [PutRecord](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html) api of the Firehose service, or you can connect a `Kinesis Data Stream` to the `Kinesis Data Firehose delivery stream`.